# Pine script symbol change

Tags: pine-script

Is it possible to listen to symbol changes in pine script? I've tried with `syminfo.ticker` in combination with the `var` keyword, but the script resets after a change of symbol.

Answer (score -1):

Good question
I don't think that's possible.
Any symbol/timeframe change triggers all the chart scripts to be reset.